# localstorage contains data before data is inserted

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Let's say we have a user object in localstorage

`window.localStorage.setItem('user', { cars: [] })`

A user clicks a button and function `foo` is called which does this:

```js
const user = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('user'));
console.log('user: ', user); // user has data here - WHY???

const flag = false;

if (!flag) {
    user.cars = [
        {
            name: 'lambo',
        }
    ];
    const updatedUser = user.cars;
    window.localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(updatedUser));
}
```

at `console.log("user: ", user)`, user object already contains an array with 1 entry for `lambo` but that entry is not added until later on.. how is this possible?

Comment: It is most likely that `window.localStorage.setItem` is invoked by the same or some other trigger and value is set.

Comment: Because you put data in local storage on a previous execution of the page.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen so what's the way around that?

Comment: to everyone who is down voting this question - this ain't the solution to a problem. This is not what SO is about. if you are going to downvote at least provide a reason a resource so I can have some way of solving this issue

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. You're using `localStorage` so the assumption is that you're trying to create persistent data. But then from the rest of your question, it seems that you don't want to create persistent data. If that's the case, why use `localStorage` at all?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I am trying to simulate a store like Redux by adding/removing data from state so different parts of the application can have access to it. So yes, I would like data to persist but also be able to update that data if need be

Comment: If you don't want that to data to survive page reloads and browser sessions, just store it in a variable. If you want it to survive page reloads, use `sessionStorage`. If you want it to survive browser sessions, use `localStorage`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Ok that makes sense thanks! However, I am still not sure by what you meant in your first statement. Can you please elaborate? How can the `cars` array contain data that is assigned later and when it has not yet been assigned any value before the `if` block?

Comment: It's just left over from the previous time the function was executed. Data in `localStorage` survives page reloads and browser sessions. So if you stored that data in a previous test 3 weeks ago, it will still be there.

Answer (score 0):

Your test does not seem to take in account that [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) data persists when you restart the page or close and re-open your browser. So your data has been stored prior to you loading it and testing.

Local Storage also saves data from different projects if you save data from the same domain, which is usually the case with local development servers (most of them use localhost and the browser shares the memory "pool" for them because of the same hostname).

If you want for data to be cleared when the user closes the browser and opens it again, use [Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). But be aware that a page refresh will not clear the session storage. Usage is exactly the same:

```js
window.sessionStorage.setItem("hello", "world");
```

However, if you do use Local Storage and need to clear everything the user has saved, you can use the `clear` method.

```js
window.localStorage.clear();
```

I can't see the reason to do it in every page load though, so you probably need to add some conditions (like check if the user has logged out or something).

Comment: I actually cleared by localStorage data in Devtools -> Applications -> localStorage to make sure there was absolutely nothing there. Upon reloading the page, the same problem occurs as I described in the code. Hence I am stumped as to why my localStorage has something in it when I just cleared it

Comment: I advise you to use `window.localStorage.clear()` before you do your test. The likelihood of your code 'executing' out of order is very, very small when compared to: 1. Your inability to clear your cache at the right location, 2. The browser containing a defect where it does not clears your cache or 3. The browser containing a cache bug that loads previous, cleared data, from storage.